# Using java class in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project. How can I use java class declared in java file from C# code? How can I reference to it?

That is what I did:
1) I've added java file to project,
2) set up build action to AndroidJavaSource
3) Compiled (and seen Foo.class in obj folder)

Foo.java

```
package x.y.z;
public class Foo{
}
```

How can I reference to Foo from C#?

```
var f = new Foo();
f.someFunction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it!

Instance is created by

```
Java.Lang.Object obj = Java.Lang.Class.ForName("x.y.z.Foo").NewInstance();
```

You can cast Java.Lang.Object to a known ancestor if necessary.